# Sum same value in array - XML php parsing

Tags: php, xml

I would like to sum value of same goods in xml.

I have this XML file with more tag ITEM and the same names like NAME, CODE, AMOUNT

[XML file](https://www.farmapesema.cz/export/orders.xml?patternId=8&hash=dea0602a8029ff268f06b9c5c2aced98d8b1e0a5255edb5866fd8bc80068425b)

and I use this php code to echo simple html:

```
    <?php

  $xml = simplexml_load_file("path") or die("Failed to load");

  $total=0;
foreach ($xml as $node){

    $row = simplexml_load_string($node->asXML());

    $result = $row->xpath("//ITEM/CODE[.='SHIPPING86']");
    $code = $row->xpath("//CODE");
    $amount = $row->xpath("//ORDER_ITEMS/ITEM/AMOUNT");
    $objednavka = implode(' ', array($code[0], $code[$n-1]));
    $mnozstvi = implode(",",$amount);
    $kod = implode(",",$code);
    $price = $row->xpath("//PRICE_TO_PAY");
    $jmeno = $row->xpath("//JMENO");
    $produkty = $row->xpath("//ITEM/NAME");
    $celkem = implode(" ",$price);

    if ($result[0])
    {

       $total += $celkem;       

    echo $objednavka . "<br />";
    echo implode(" ",$jmeno) . "<br />";
    echo implode(" ",$price) . "<br />";
    echo implode("<br />",$produkty) . $mnozstvi . "<br />";    

    }
}

echo '<h3>Celkem ' . $total; "</h3>";

?>
```

How can I sum value of the same item? If I have same goods with CODE = 6, I need to count it. Can you help me, please.

This is an ideal output, unique delivery place, that has already tag ITEM, and sum of product, which can be delivered to this place.

XML

````
<ORDERS>
<ITEM>
<NAME>Čtvrtek - Chodov</NAME>
<AMOUNT>1</AMOUNT>
<CODE>SHIPPING86</CODE>
</ITEM>
<ITEM>
<NAME>Jarní zeleninová bedýnka pro dva</NAME>
<CODE>7</CODE>
<AMOUNT>3</AMOUNT>
<COUNT>2</COUNT>
</ITEM>
<ITEM>
<NAME>Jarní mix</NAME>
<CODE>77</CODE>
<AMOUNT>1</AMOUNT>
<COUNT>1</COUNT>
</ITEM>
<ITEM>
<NAME>Jarní rodinná zeleninová bedýnka</NAME>
<CODE>6</CODE>
<AMOUNT>6</AMOUNT>
<COUNT>5</COUNT>
</ITEM>
<ITEM>
<NAME>Brambory 10 kg</NAME>
<CODE>4</CODE>
<AMOUNT>10</AMOUNT>
<COUNT>2</COUNT>
</ITEM>
<ITEM>
<NAME>Česnek 1 kg</NAME>
<CODE>89</CODE>
<AMOUNT>3</AMOUNT>
<COUNT>3</COUNT>
</ITEM>
<ITEM>
<NAME>Brambory 5 kg</NAME>
<CODE>9</CODE>
<AMOUNT>2</AMOUNT>
<COUNT>2</COUNT>
</ITEM>
<ITEM>
<NAME>Rodinná zeleninová bedýnka</NAME>
<CODE>1</CODE>
<AMOUNT>2</AMOUNT>
<COUNT>2</COUNT>
</ITEM>
<ITEM>
<NAME>Ředkvičky 1 svazek</NAME>
<CODE>137</CODE>
<AMOUNT>33</AMOUNT>
<COUNT>14</COUNT>
</ITEM>
<ITEM>
<NAME>Jablečný mošt 3 l</NAME>
<CODE>110</CODE>
<AMOUNT>5</AMOUNT>
<COUNT>3</COUNT>
</ITEM>
<ITEM>
<NAME>Zeleninová bedýnka pro dva</NAME>
<CODE>3</CODE>
<AMOUNT>1</AMOUNT>
<COUNT>1</COUNT>
</ITEM>
<ITEM>
<NAME>Denní porce zeleniny</NAME>
<CODE>74</CODE>
<AMOUNT>4</AMOUNT>
<COUNT>4</COUNT>
</ITEM>
<ITEM>
<NAME>Mix sušeného ovoce</NAME>
<CODE>104</CODE>
<AMOUNT>1</AMOUNT>
<COUNT>1</COUNT>
</ITEM>
<ITEM>
<NAME>Brambory 25 kg</NAME>
<CODE>2</CODE>
<AMOUNT>1</AMOUNT>
<COUNT>1</COUNT>
</ITEM>
</ORDERS>

    ```
````

Comment: 470,00 +  270,00  + 250,00 + 350,00 + 300,00 + 630,00  + 270,00 + 310,00 + 350,00 = 3200 it seems that it is detected all values correctly and summing it

Comment: if you select $result = $row->xpath("//ITEM/CODE[.='6']");

Comment: instead of $result = $row->xpath("//ITEM/CODE[.='SHIPPING86']");

Comment: did it solve your problem ?

Comment: who is $n ?? $objednavka = implode(' ', array($code[0], $code[$n-1]));

Comment: I would lik to count specific item, which can be detected ba CODE. In XML feed it can be multible vaiant of goods. I have goods from 1 to 200 and this value is savedin tag CODE, but in XML, there are much more tag CODE (it is used for delivery, for order Id, for billing) but I only need to count goods with tag CODE